# Smarty: unrecognized tag 'literal'

Tags: tags, smarty

I thought that enclosing the javascript-block in a {literal}...{/literal} block will prevent smarty from parsing it, but...

This code in `troll.tpl` causes Syntax Error: `unrecognized tag 'literal'`, dunno why.

```
{literal}
    <script>
        ....
    </script>
{/literal}
```

PHP 5.5 and Smarty 2.6

Comment: Please, post the whole error message as it is shown on screen

Comment: It should work without any problem. Create simple PHP script that only uses Smarty and displays this template file and check if any error occurs

Comment: You should also make sure that you haven't changed standard Smarty delimiters { and } to other characters

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem.
The error comes, because I wanted to patch smarty by change deprecated `preg_match("/.../e");` to `preg_match_callback(...);`, but now I restored changes and then I modified my `error_reporting(E_ALL  & ~E_WARNING);` to `error_reporting(E_ALL  & ~E_WARNING & ~E_DEPRECATED);` And now everything works well.